# Windows forms pass List to a new form

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I pass a variable to another form?

I created the following class:

```
class Cart
{
    private string productName;
    private int qtd;
    private decimal price;

    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }

        set
        {
            price = value;
        }
    }

    public string ProductName
    {
        get
        {
            return productName;
        }

        set
        {
            productName = value;
        }
    }

    public int Qtd
    {
        get
        {
            return qtd;
        }

       set
        {
            qtd = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have one form that I add values to my cart:

```
public partial class frmProducts : Form
{

    List<Cart> cartList = new List<Cart>();

    private void btnAddCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(txtQtd.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter how many items do you want.", "Products", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            return;
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtQtd.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(lblQtd.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We onlye have " + lblQtd.Text + " items in stock.", "Products", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            return;
        }

        Cart cart = new Cart();
        cart.ProductName = lblProductName.Text;
        cart.Qtd = Convert.ToInt32(lblQtd.Text);
        cart.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(lblPrice.Text);

        cartList.Add(cart);
    }
}
```

I haave another WindowsForms that will work with the cartList. How can I send the cartList to the new WindowsForms?

Comment: Try to think from the scope of variables if they are required global level then better make them global. And also creating Entity Classes to store and pass on the global data is lot easier.

Comment: You can put the cart to the main form as a static property `public static List<Cart> Cart { Private set; get; }`, initialize it in your main form. Use it with MainForm.Cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `frmProcessCart` be the next form where you need the `cartList` to proceed. For that you can use any of the following options:

- Get `List<Cart>` in the Constructor of that form:

Which means you have to pass the `cartList` as to the new form through its constructor, so you will get the same instance of the list their and you can proceed with that as well. In this case the Constructor of that form looks like this:

```
 public frmProcessCart(List<Cart> cartList)
 {
     // Something here if needed            
 }
```

- Another option is make `cartList` as static field:

In this case you can access the `cartList` from any other forms in the applications through frmProducts.cartList, you need not to pass any instance or create any instance of the `frmProducts`. in this case the definition of the cartList will be like this

```
public partial class frmProducts : Form
{
    public static List<Cart> cartList = new List<Cart>();
    // Rest of code here
}
```

Comment: I tried to make cartList static, but I get the error: a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Comment: Hope that the issue is with the place where you declare the List, Make sure that the definition belongs to the class `frmProducts`. see updates

Answer (score 1):

In the new windows form declare a property for the cartList. Set the property before you show that form. Then your new form can work with that property.